# How can I include ossia without creating a blank space?

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to add an ossia staff above the upper staff of a grand
staff. Working from [this mailing list post](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2012-12/msg00369.html), I have
constructed a minimal example that *almost* does what I want. The
problem is that the entire score contains a blank space for the ossia
staff, even in systems that have no ossia.

Here is the example (truly, a melodious composition):

```tex
\version "2.18.2"

ossia = \new Staff = "ossia" \with {
  \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
  fontSize = #-2
  \override StaffSymbol #'staff-space = #(magstep -2)
  \override Clef #'transparent = ##t
  \override KeySignature #'stencil = ##f
} {
  \key b \major
  \override Staff.BarLine #'allow-span-bar = ##f
  \stopStaff
  s2.*100  % ???
}

treble = \new Staff = "treble" {
  \clef treble
  \key b \major
  \relative c' {
    \repeat unfold 10 { b8 cis dis fis dis cis }
    b4 dis fis |
    b4
    <<
      { dis, fis }
      \context Staff = "ossia" {
        \startStaff \tuplet 3/2 { dis8 b dis } fis4 \stopStaff
      }
    >> |
    b2. |
  }
}

bass = \new Staff = "bass" {
  \clef bass
  \key b \major
  \relative c {
    \repeat unfold 12 { fis,4 fis4 fis4 | }
    b2.
  }
}

pianoStaff = \new PianoStaff {
  \compressFullBarRests
  \time 3/4
  <<
    \ossia
    \treble
    \bass
  >>
}

\paper {
  #(set-paper-size "letter")
  indent = 25\mm
  short-indent = 5\mm
}

\score {
  << \pianoStaff >>
  % This changes nothing:
  % \layout { \context { \Staff \RemoveEmptyStaves } }
}
```

[Here is the output (PNG image, 85 KB).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2mxO.png)

Some interesting things to note:

- If I remove the `s2.*100` at line 13 (marked `% ???`), or change the
  value to anything smaller than 12, the ossia staff renders
  completely incorrectly. It appears below the bass clef, includes the
  clef and time signature, and is in the key of C (i.e., the rendered
  notes include accidentals). Basically, it looks like it's failed to
  notice that the `ossia` staff exists and has constructed a brand new
  one. I suspect that this is because the ossia staff is supposed to
  extend past each point where it is used—i.e., when switching staff
  contexts, one can go "back in time" but not forward. I don't really
  understand this, but I can live with it, as it doesn't seem to have
  an intrinsic effect as long as `\compressFullBarRests` is enabled.
- I have included the paper size in the MWE to force consistent
  dimensions on different systems.
- As I noted in the score, adding `\RemoveEmptyStaves` does not remove
  the empty staves.

My question is: **how can I keep the ossia staff rendered as it does in
this example** (small and above the treble clef) **without adding the
empty space on all previous systems?**

Answer (score 1):

\RemoveEmptyStaves is not working because the staves are within a PianoStaff, so you must add `\remove "Keep_alive_together_engraver"` to the \layout block. Here's a minimal example of a documentation snippet slightly modified:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\new PianoStaff
<<
  \new Staff = "ossia" \with {
    \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
    \hide Clef
    fontSize = #-3
    \override StaffSymbol.staff-space = #(magstep -3)
    \override StaffSymbol.thickness = #(magstep -3)
  } \relative c'' {
    R1*3
    c4 e8 d c2
  }
  \new Staff \relative c' {
    c4 b c2
    e4 f e2
    g4 a g2 \break
    c4 b c2
    g4 a g2
    e4 d c2
  }
>>

\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff \RemoveEmptyStaves
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-first = ##t
  }
  \context {
    \PianoStaff
    \remove "Keep_alive_together_engraver"
  }
}
```

Your example is quite big, not a real MWE. `s2.*100` doesn't make any sense to me. I suggest that you submit a smaller example.

Comment: Hi fedelibre. I appreciate your help. Thanks to your answer, I was able to figure out a satisfactory solution. A few comments. First, the purpose of the spacer rest is so that I can write the ossia by simply setting `\context Staff = "ossia"` within the flow of the rest of the score (as in my example), as opposed to manually inserting the correct number of rests to advance the ossia to the exact desired position (as in yours). Second, your example doesn't display the ossia properly, as it includes extra blank measures for all bars in the system in which an ossia appears. For instance, (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) if you move your `\break` to the previous line, then there is an extra empty bar before the ossia's content. (Please consult the rendered image link in my original post.) This is the purpose of the `\startStaff` and `\stopStaff` commands in my original example. Third, I'm sorry that my MWE is large. Now that I have a working solution, I can see that (e.g.) the bass clef is indeed not required. I wasn't sure about this, because it is a `\PianoStaff`, after all. All is easier with hindsight! :-) Here is my minimal solution: https://gist.github.com/wchargin/db8f3ff0129686dafe87045f90c8bf5f